# Salvar Imagens do CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Olá, estou querendo salvar uma imagem no banco de dados. Estou usando o seguinte:

```
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/fotos/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
  $config['max_size']     = '512000';
  $config['max_width']  = '2440';
  $config['max_height']  = '1600';
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  $this->upload->do_upload('arquivo');
  $imagem = $this->upload->data();
  $file_url = base_url("assets/fotos/{$imagem['file_name']}");
```

Já o meu input está assim:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<label class="col-sm-2">Imagem do Produto:</label>
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" size="99999" class="col-sm-7">
</div>
```

Para salvar a imagem, além do método insert no model tenho no método de insert:

```
"foto" => $file_url
```

O que acontece, está salvado o caminho da foto(sem o arquivo em questão é claro), por exemplo:

**http://[::1]/NomeMeuAPP/assets/fotos/**

Mas não está salvando a foto na pasta informada. O que estou esquecendo? Obrigado.

Comment: Tem certeza que o diretório em questão está com permissão para escrita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas possibilidades como:

- O tamanho máximo do arquivo pode estar excedendo o tamanho em MB permitido pelo php.ini;
- (Principalmente) se for Linux você terá que adicionar permissão de escrita para seu usuário e grupo no diretório em que está tentando salvar as imagens;
- O formulário deve conter o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Exemplo: `<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Quando fizer o upload verifique a mensagem de erro em uma condicional.

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('arquivo')) {
    // Se deu erro...
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();

} else {
   // Segue processamento...
}
```